# Can I change styling for a specific value in YAxis in recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using recharts to create a visual in react, here is how my y-axis looks like:

```
<YAxis dataKey="XYZ" unit="%" yAxisId="rightY" >
    <Label value="XYZ" position="insideRight" />
</YAxis>

<Line yAxisId="rightY" type="linear" dataKey="XYZ">
     <LabelList dataKey="XYZ"content={this.customizedLineLabel} />
</Line>
```

Is it possible to change the font color of a particular value in y-axis?

For example: [if this is my visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcBfA.png)

I want to change the color of 0 in y-axis (marked in red)

I checked the API documentation, I did not find anything related to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible and very easy to implement as well.
You will need to create a customTick function which will be passed to tick property of Yaxis.

[image]

And in that function you add following code. `<Text>` is provided by recharts.

[image]

I hope this is what you wanted!

[image]

Visit the whole code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-voice-5pnx3j?file=/src/Components/CustomTooltipAndLegendComponent.jsx)